# vespa-model-inspect throws Segmentation fault on Redhat 7.6

Tags: vespa

Getting Segmentation fault when executing any of the vespa-model-inspect commands. Vespa version 7.22.18

- log_debug_message 'Starting vespa-model-inspect with : ' env LD_PRELOAD=/opt/vespa/lib64/vespa/malloc/libvespamalloc.so vespa-model-inspect-bin hosts
- '[' '' ']'
- exec env LD_PRELOAD=/opt/vespa/lib64/vespa/malloc/libvespamalloc.so vespa-model-inspect-bin hosts
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)

yum list | grep vespa

vespa.x86_64                    7.22.18-1.el7    @group_vespa-vespa
.....

Comment: I was able to successfully execute vespa-model-inspect-bin hosts

Answer (score 2):

Trying to reproduce, how did you install Vespa in this environment?

I was able to run vespa-model-inspect after installing Vespa 7.22.18 on RHEL 7.6  following the guide on https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/vespa-quick-start-multinode-aws.html

Comment: I am using linux servers and not docker images.

I performed the following steps to install vespa package.

yum -y install yum-utils epel-release

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/vespa/vespa/repo/epel-7/group_vespa-vespa-epel-7.repo

yum -y install vespa bind-utils

Comment: We tried some more today but we were unable to reproduce - it seemed to work well. If you have a coredump, perhaps you can upload that somewhere? As you said you were able to successfully execute the command later, I hope the problem is now solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

The VESPA_HOSTNAME property value in the /opt/vespa/var/jdisc_core/configserver.properties was wrong as the node was cloned from another server. Once this config was fixed the commands are returning expected result.